# Do any of the other founders of the Dollars ever show up again?

Tags: durarara

So, we all know that

> Tanaka Taro, a.k.a. Ryuugamine Mikado

founded the Dollars.

But he wasn't the only one - in episode 11, we see that he founded the Dollars along with some other folks he met online, including at least 閣下 ("Kakka"), GG, and ZAWA.

[image: the original, pre-Dollars chatroom]

The show indicates that these other people eventually left when the Dollars began to spin out of control. But Durarara is a show that does a ridiculously good job of conserving detail, especially with respect to its characters. This leads me to my question: do any of the other founders of the Dollars show up again later on in any capacity?

Comment: I'm not too sure but at first I thought Aoba might've been one of them. Probably not but the fact that he just happened to guess that Mikado was a higher up in the dollars from the meet up seemed far fetched.